# Pandas find mean of values for specific time period

Tags: pandas, mean

This is my first time posting here and I hope I am doing it right. I have searched the forum for my question, and even though there are related topics, none have addressed my specific question, so I hope you can help me.

I have a data frame with two columns that simplified looks like this:

```
    Date         Value
0   20010425     1
1   20010112     4
2   20010308     3
3   20010527     5
4   20010620     2
```

The first column represents dates in the yyyymmdd format, but is int64.
Now I want to create an additional column, that takes the mean of the value of the previous 3 months individually for each row:

```
      Date       Value     Mean_Value_past_3_months
0   20010425     1         3.5                      #(4+3)/2
1   20010130     4         NaN                      # since no date earlier than 20010130 is available 
2   20010308     3         4                        
3   20010527     5         2                        # (1+3)/2
4   20010620     2         3                        # (1+5)/2
```

And then I would like to drop NaN, so it does not count them moving forward.

I have tried to transpose the dates and then do, which is something I have found on here:

```
s = subset.columns[0:].values < df.values[:,None]
df['mean'] = (subset.iloc[:,0:]*t).mean(1)
```

but it a) it does not work yet, and b) does not include the 3 months period.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit ambiguous how you want to define the "previous three months" but what you can do is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": [20010425, 20010112, 20010308, 20010527, 20010620],
                   "Value": [1, 4, 3, 5, 2]
                   })
# define a custom function that computes the mean of the last three months
def get_mean(row):
    # choose the correct dates here using the passed row parameter:
    # e.g.
    yyyymmdd_start = row["Date"] - 300
    yyyymmdd_end = row["Date"]

    selected_dates = df[(df['Date'] > yyyymmdd_start) & (df['Date'] < yyyymmdd_end)]

    return selected_dates["Value"].mean()

df["Mean_Value_past_3_months"] = df.apply(get_mean, axis=1)

print(df)
```

```
Out[115]: 
       Date  Value  Mean_Value_past_3_months
0  20010425      1                       3.0
1  20010112      4                       NaN
2  20010308      3                       4.0
3  20010527      5                       2.0
4  20010620      2                       3.0
```

Comment: Hi Andre, thank you very much for your help!!
When you say "choose the correct dates here" what do you mean by that? Because the starting date is different for each row, and then I look at the past 3 months for each row individually. Could you please elaborate?
(Fyi: The code works, but it does give me a value for the earliest date, which it shouldn't)

Comment: In the `get_mean()` function, the `row` parameter contains the info for that row. So `row["Date"]` is the date value for the passed row (for the row with index 3, that would be `20010527`. 
I subtract 300 for this value to get the date (in yyyymmdd format) of 3 months ago. This isn't optimal but it was just an easy way to get 3 months away form the date in a given row. That's why I say choose a correct way. 
`selected_dates` is then the DataFrame which contains only the rows within the selected time interval (of 3 months)
Finally the function returns the mean of the values. Hope that helps

Comment: As Phil Leh does below, you could make your life easier by converting the date format to a format, with which pandas works natively. That opens up many more possibilities.

Comment: Absolutely makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to convert the integer dates to datetime and use [pandas.DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) capabilities like so:

```py
import pandas as pd

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%Y%m%d')

# Sorting by Date, because rolling() need monotonic dates
df = df.sort_values('Date')

# Using approximately 30 days per month -> 90 day for 3 months, hence '90D'
df['Means'] = df.rolling('90D', on='Date', closed='left').mean()['Value']
print(df)
```

This will result in:

```py
        Date  Value  Means
1 2001-01-30      4    NaN
2 2001-03-08      3    4.0
0 2001-04-25      1    3.5
3 2001-05-27      5    2.0
4 2001-06-20      2    3.0
```